# How do I (not) drift in Twister Race?

Tags: nintendo-land

When playing Captain Falcon's Twister Race, I seem to drift a lot, whether or not I intend to. This can be a bit annoying, as it tends to slow forward progress unless you know exactly what you're doing. I'd very much like to not drift, but I haven't seen much telling me about drifting (only a loading-screen-tip that doesn't say how), so I don't know what to stop doing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, buried deep in the electronic manual page for Twister Race is guidance on drifting: Turn the controller suddenly. So a drift is initiated when you enter a turn sharply. Turn the controller smoothly, and you'll steer normally.